# Jcrop distorcendo a imagem no momento da seleção

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jcrop

Quero utilizar o Jcrop em um `.dialog()`, mas não esta funcionando corretamente, a seleção do Jcrop esta ficando errada, distorcendo a imagem:

[image: Seleção incorreta da área de corte]

Em vez de fazer assim:

[image: Seleção correta da área de corte]

O js está assim:

```
$('.imagem_principal').live('click', function() {
    var foto = $(this).parent().parent().find('a').attr('href');

    var form = '<div id="box-crop"><img src="'+foto+'" id="foto-crop"></div>';

    $(form).dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) { 
            $("#foto-crop").Jcrop({
                setSelect: [0, 0, 140, 360],
                minSize: [140, 360],
                aspectRatio: 1
            }); 
        },
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: "Corte imagem principal",
        buttons: {
            "Cortar foto": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Cancelar": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no css, o arquivo css de minha aplicação continha duas classes em comum com com o css do jcrop, foi só alterar que funcionou. Minhas classes estavam forçando o tamanho da imagem, por esse motivo a área da seleção ficava distorcida.

Answer (score 1):

Você está definindo `aspectRatio: 1` o que significa que deseja que a área de corte tenha uma proporção fixa, nesse caso um quadrado perfeito, enquanto a seleção que você define não se trata de um quadrado `setSelect: [0, 0, 140, 360]`.

Caso você não queira fixar a proporção do corte, essa propriedade deve ser omitida (não tenho certeza se o valor default é 0).

Tente isso:

```
$("#foto-crop").Jcrop({
    setSelect: [0, 0, 140, 360],
    minSize: [140, 360]
});
```

Outro exemplo de uso do aspectRatio, se quisesse uma proporção fixada para 16:9 (HDTV) definiria `aspectRatio: 16 / 9`.

Comment: mesmo retirando o aspectRatio, continua selecionando errado, esta repetindo a imagem na área de seleção ao invés de selecionar apenas a área marcada,e quando movo a área selecionada para direita, a seleção fica como se estivesse vazia.

Comment: ah, valeu pela dica do aspectRatio: 16 / 9 +1